# Document Planning and MicroPlanning to build NLG Model using SimpleNLG

Tags: nlp, nlg

I am trying to build an NLG Model which would be domain specific. I came across SimpleNLG which I think is a good starting point but looks like it only supports Realisation and not "Document Planning and Micro Planning" 
as specified in the link below: 
https://code.google.com/p/simplenlg/wiki/AppendixA

Can anyone point me some links to get started to build an NLG Model, mainly on how to do Document and Micro Planning?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also want to take a look at OpenCCG (http://openccg.sourceforge.net/). Depending on the hand-crafted ontology (that you have to provide) you may be able to specify the structure in terms of that ontology which could serve the purpose of the micro-planning step from the Dale&Reiter's paper.

Answer (score 2):

There is a little bit of support for microplanning in simplenlg - it has a module for simple syntactic aggregation.

As far as I know there are no easily available libraries for document planning and microplanning. The main problem is that the input to NLG systems varies quite a lot and so there is no clear "input". This means that everyone ends up implementing their own data structures and algorithms. You can have a look at some existing NLG systems to see how they implement these thing ([here](http://aclweb.org/aclwiki/index.php?title=Downloadable_NLG_systems)). Perhaps NaturalOWL might be a good candidate if you are working with java.

If you are planning to implement something yourself, have a look at [Dale & Reiter 2000 - Building NLG systems](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Building-Natural-Language-Generation-Processing/dp/052102451X). It is a bit dated now but most of the ideas are still relevant. You will find there some example code as well.